# How to disable cell click of grid

Tags: java, gwt, grid, cell

I want to know if there is a way to disable clicking on a certain cell of a grid once its value is set in Google Web Toolkit?I tried `setEnabled(false)`, but it's not defined for cell

Comment: I have tried the suggested solution but still not working .The problem is that I am setting the fields of the grid by setText(...) and then I cannot disable clicking the cell which was already set!!Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the cell and overwrite the onBrowserEvent method with something like that:

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
  switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
  case Event.ONCLICK:
    if (condition) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      break;
    } else {
      super.onBrowserEvent(event);
      break;
    }
  default:
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    break;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your table:

```
myCellTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<T>() {

    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<T> event) {
        // Change 2 to the index of your column
        if ("mousedown".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType()) &&
            event.getContext().getColumn() == 2) {
            event.setCanceled(true);
        }
    }
```